# How to get the left distance between TextView's View and Text?

Tags: android

How can I get the left distance between a TextView's View and Text? I have tried following ways:

```
TextView.getPaddingLeft()  // returns 0;
TextView.getLayout().getLineLeft(0)  // returns 504424 (What is this? Obviously not pixels)
```

How can I get the distance in pixels?

Comment: If you don't put any padding, the distance will be 0. Be careful with the background, if it is 9-patch it has its own padding. Other than that padding should work. Second line should be the coordinate on device screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below snippet to get an idea:

```
int location[] = new int[2];
yourView.getLocationInWindow(location);
```

Here, i think, location[0] will house the x-coordinate and location[1] will house the y-coordinare. Just check this.

Depending on whether its x or y coordinate, subtract the distance between your TextView view and Text view to get the relevant distance between your two views.